# How to include sub-dependency only for dependency that needs it

Tags: java, json, spring, maven

I have a following problem. I use GSON to create my JSONs for unit tesing Spring controller, but the other dependency I use (Maven by the way) to create [json web tokens](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt), depends on Jackson. For some reason it overrides GSON or interferes in some way anyway, throws errors about JSON format being wrong (it doesn't understand enums, and can't parse them) and it destroys my unit test.

So my question is - is there any way to force sub-dependency to be used only for dependency that needs it?

Comment: AFAIK a JAR is either in your classpath at runtime, or it's not.  So if you have a collision you should square that away if possible.

Comment: You mean that there is no way to do that and I should try to resolve the conflict?

Comment: You can post some of your code, but I would say that you should avoid using two JARs which might conflict because this could cause a problem in production.

Comment: Couple of questions - 1. what is the scope of the GSON dependency you are using? 2. Are you using json web tokens as a part of unit testing or it a part of the main application?

Comment: @asg I'm using GSON for tests and web tokens as a part of a maing app. I did not change scopes, going to try.